# Derivation of the Biot-Savart Law

Tags: electromagnetism

Can someone provide a derivation of the [Biot-Savart law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) for electromagnetic induction? To be clear, 
$$
d\vec{B}~=~\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{I d\vec{\ell}\times \vec{r}}{r^3}.
$$

Is there a simple way to compute the magnetic field at a point between two Helmholtz coils, if the radii of the coils are the same and the current through each coil is the same?

Comment: What should the law be derived from?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, From Ampere's Law, preferably.

Comment: I consistant derivation would be interesting to see. This is a good conceptual question, I absolutely dont seevwhy 2 closevoters think this should be closed.

Comment: I dont understand why has this question been marked as aduplicate when the question given in the link is actually a duplicate of this question!

Answer (score 3):

In the static case you can solve Maxwell equations using a vector potential via the poisson equatuion for the magnetic potential.

$\Delta \vec A(\vec r)=-\mu_0 \vec J(\vec r)$

Using the Greens function for the Laplace operator yields the solution of this differential equation.

$\vec A(\vec r)=\frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi}\int d^3r'  \frac{\vec J(\vec r')}{|{\vec r-\vec r'}|}$

Now we can calculate the B field via  $\vec B = \vec\nabla \times \vec A$ and use the identity $\vec\nabla\times(\phi\vec A)=\phi(\vec\nabla\times(\vec A))-\vec A\times\vec\nabla\phi $. Additionally we have to calculate the gradient of the scalar function 1/|(r-r')|. This gives the Bio Savart law.

Comment: What is '$rot$'? Furthermore, I am not convinced that you can do what you have stated. I want to see the entire thing!

Comment: rot is the german word of curl, I'm sorry for that. Which point is not clear or what do you think I can not do?

Comment: I don't see how you can derive the full expression from what you have said...

Comment: @Killercam: you can get to the Biot-Savart law from Noldig's answer for the vector potential by using explicitely cartesian coordinates and vector basis.

Answer (score 0):

It is an experimental law not derivable from other more basic laws

Comment: I think this is wrong. You can derive it directly from Maxwell equations, which are more fundamental from my point of view.

Comment: And how do you think Maxwell equations have been obtained? I think from Coulomb and Biot-Savart laws!

Comment: ok, historically you are correct. Let's say they follow from each other, or they are consistent.

Comment: OK,people! Historically, Biot-Savart's Law -> Maxwell Equations -> Special Relativity

But, I think now, you'll all agree that Special Relativity is the most fundamental of them all. So, why not use Special Relativity to give derivation of Biot-Savart's Law?
I think I might write an answer