# If Ampere's law implies the Biot-Savart law, which implies Gauss's law for magnetism, does that mean Maxwell's equations are redundant?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, maxwell-equations

Studying electromagnetism, I came across the following fact:

- Maxwell's third equation (divergence of magnetic field is zero) can be derived from the Biot-Savart Law.
- The Biot-Savart Law can be derived from Maxwell-Ampère's Law

Hence, it seems that the four equations are redundant.

Unfortunately I've not found anything about this, so I ask: it is true?

EDIT:
For the sake of completeness, this is the proof of the 3rd equation (this is basically Griffith's proof):

\begin{eqnarray}
\vec{B}(r) &=& \iiint_K \frac{\mu_0 i}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{j} \times \vec{r}}{r^3} d\tau'\\
&=& \iiint_K \frac{\mu_0 i}{4 \pi} \ \vec{j} \times \nabla\left(-\frac{1}{r}\right) d\tau'
\end{eqnarray}
Applying divergence to both terms we obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{div} \vec{B} &=& \frac{\mu_0 i}{4 \pi} \iiint_K \text{div} \left(\vec{j} \times \nabla\left(-\frac{1}{r}\right)\right) d\tau'\\
&=& \frac{\mu_0 i}{4 \pi} \iiint_K \nabla \times \vec{j} \cdot \nabla\left(-\frac{1}{r}\right) - \vec{j} \cdot \nabla \times \nabla\left(-\frac{1}{r}\right) d\tau' \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}

The last term is zero since the curl of a gradient is always zero and the divergence of $\vec{j}$ is zero ($\vec{j}$ depends on primed coordinates only).

And this is the derivation of the Biot-Savart Law from the Maxwell-Ampère Law: [Is Biot-Savart law obtained empirically or can it be derived?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67445/is-biot-savart-law-obtained-empirically-or-can-it-be-derived)

Comment: Please show the details of your proof.

Comment: I've added the proof / references.

Comment: With your definition of "redundant", any math theorem is redundant. All you'd need would be axioms.

Comment: That's not really what I meant. Maxwell's equations in a certain sense are the axioms of electromagnetism theory, so my question was whether one of the axioms could be derived from the other axioms (so it would actually be a theorem).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since there is no magnetic charge term in the Biot-Savart law, it is only correct if Gauss's law for magnetism ($\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$) is true and there are no magnetic monopoles.  So it makes sense that Gauss's law can be derived from the Biot-Savart law.

However, the Biot-Savart law cannot be derived from the Maxwell-Ampère Law without implicitly assuming Gauss's law.  In general, we know this both because of the lack of a magnetic charge term and because as Giorgio pointed out, the curl and divergence of a vector field are independent quantities. 
 The specific problem with [the proof you cited](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67445/is-biot-savart-law-obtained-empirically-or-can-it-be-derived) is that it assumes that a continuous vector potential $\mathbf{A}$ can be constructed such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$, which is not true if there are magnetic monopoles.

Answer (score 6):

Curl and divergence of a vector field are independent quantities ( [Helmholtz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) allows to reconstruct a vector field if **both** are known). So, it is impossible to deduce anything for each of these two quantities from the other.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Biot-Savart Law is equivalent to Helmholtz's theorem for a divergence-free vector field.  Similarly, Coulomb's Law is equivalent to Helmholtz's theorem for a curl-free vector field.