# Biot-Savart law in 2D using Geometric Algebra

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, clifford-algebra

The Biot-Savart law can be [derived](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67445/) from Maxwell's equations for 3D using the vector product (via the curl). On the other hand, in a purely two-dimensional (2D) world, the vector product is not well defined and, therefore, its derivation is not mathematically feasible. For this situation, despite [some efforts](http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/2dem.pdf), it seems convenient to formulate the problem using [Geometric Algebra](https://www.usc.gal/fagms/Publicaciones/2021/Orb%C3%A1n_2021_Eur._J._Phys._42_015204.pdf).

I would be interested in knowing the formulation of the Biot-Savart law in 2D to obtain the magnetic field at a generic point.
According to my intuition, the magnetic field should be a bivector, but I'm not sure.