Where comes the Biot-Savart formula from?
I learned about the Biot-Savart Law recently. I understand how to calculate magnet fields with it, but where does this formula $$dB=...$$ come from?
My professor just told me we do that in theoretical physics.
But I am to curious, can someone show me?

It's a limit of Maxwell's equations which are an experimental fact.

It is the general solution for a differential equation, that is called Ampère-Maxwell equation.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67445/2451 and links therein.
