# Prove Biot-Savart law, assuming that $\vec{A}=\frac I c\int \frac{d\vec{L}}{r}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Prove [Biot-Savart law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law), assuming that 
$$\vec{A}=\frac I c\int \frac{d\vec{L}}{r}$$
$$\vec{B}=\nabla\times \vec{A}$$
Any hint on what to do next?

Comment: related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64751/

Answer (score 1):

For staters, try putting $\vec A$ into $\vec B$.

You need to find an identity that helps you put:

## $\nabla \times ({I\over c}\int {d\vec L \over r})$

into something more useful. (Most people don't know this off the top of their heads, but your book's appendix or other math tables should be quite helpful!)

Some more algebra should follow, but you should be able to get the Biot-Savart Law from this.

Comment: I didnt find anything useful in the internet, should I just try to evaluate this: $\int {d\vec L \over r}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Integration

Answer (score 1):

If what are you trying to write is:

$$
\overrightarrow{A}(r) = \frac{I}{c} \oint \frac{d \overrightarrow{L}(r')}{|r - r'|}  $$
Where $ d \overrightarrow{L} $ is the line element of the circuit, then you could use this identity:
$$
\nabla \wedge (f \overrightarrow{A}) = f \; \nabla \wedge \overrightarrow{A} + \nabla f \wedge \overrightarrow{A}
$$
to get:
$$
\overrightarrow{B}(r) = \frac{I}{c} \nabla_r \wedge \oint \frac{d \overrightarrow{L}(r')}{|r - r'|} =  \frac{I}{c} \oint \nabla_r \left( \frac{1}{|r-r'|}\right) \wedge d \overrightarrow{L}(r')
$$
Now you use that
$$
\nabla_r \left( \frac{1}{|r-r'|}\right) = -\frac{\overrightarrow{r} - \overrightarrow{r'}}{|r-r'|^3}
$$
To finally get Biot-Savart law:
$$
\overrightarrow{B}(r) = \frac{I}{c} \; \oint \frac{d \overrightarrow{L}(r') \wedge (\overrightarrow{r} - \overrightarrow{r'})}{|r-r'|^3} 
$$

Comment: why this was downvoted?

Comment: Could be because you directly answered what looks like a homework question (though it wasn't me)!